# Replace every occurence of characters by another characters

Tags: bash

I need to replace characters '.' '-' '+' and '§' with 'D' '_' 'P' '-' in the same order, so I ve found that you can use sed with "y" option like this:

```
echo "$string" | sed 'y/.-+§/D_P-/'
```

Which is working perfectly on localhost terminal. But when I run the script serverside it put an error to stderr:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: strings for `y' command are different lengths
```

And the script istn working. I ve searched for a long time and it seems that option 'y' isnt that popular since I havent found much results for my searching.
Interesting is that when I put the space after "-" in /D_P- everything is working. I tried even escape some characters "+" and ".". Not working.
Has anyone any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `s/` instead of `y/`? (It would require some escaping, of course.)

Comment: You should terminate the sed expression with a trailing / `sed 'y/.-+§/D_P-/'`

Comment: The local and server character set (as seen by bash and used to decode the parameter passed to `sed`) may differ w.r.t. the number of bytes to which § gets encoded. What does `echo $LANG` output in both shells? What do you get for `echo -n '§' | od -x`?

Comment: @Biffen 's/' doesnt allow me what I need - I'd have to put more 'sed' commands

Comment: @FloHimself Yeah I forgot  about that yet still correct in code

Comment: @halfbit It echo both the same

Comment: @Croolman What is the version of `sed` on each machine? Your remote server's `sed` doesn't appear to understand UTF-8 input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `sed 'y/.-+§/D_P-/'` could be replaced with `tr`, like this:

```
echo "$string" | tr '.-+§' 'D_P-'
```

Does this works for you?

Comment: Although an arguably cleaner alternative to the `sed` command, this would probably suffer from the same character encoding issue as the given `sed` command if `tr` is not utf-8 aware.

Comment: @jim That is working as intended. As always - most of it starts with (my) poor knowledge of language. Thanks!